# PostgreSQL keeps connections made by Go open

Tags: postgresql, go, database-connection

Using the Go cron package I run the following code every second:

```
func dbPGConnectionCount(db *sql.DB) (int64, error) {
    var connectionCount int64
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT count(1) from pg_stat_activity;`)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&connectionCount)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
    }
    return connectionCount, err
}
```

where `db` is a connection pool for connections to PostgreSQL.

Thanks to the `defer` statement I expected that PostgreSQL wouldn't keep any connections open. However, soon after starting my program, when I check with `select * from pg_stat_activity` I see new idle queries being added every second.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As documented, that closes the rows iterator, not the database connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. That's how connection pooling works. Your `defer` releases the connection *back to the pool*. It's kept open intentionally, so that the next time your database is needed, your application doesn't have to wait for a new connection handshake, it can just re-use the existing connection. That's pretty much the definition of a connection pool.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know but can this be tuned? I set my max connections to 100 and soon it's not possible to make new connections any more.

Comment: I see I can do `db.SetMaxOpenConns(n)`

Comment: There are 3 methods for tuning the connection pool: https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetConnMaxLifetime, https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns and https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.SetMaxOpenConns

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. I will probably accept in 2 or 3 days.